# Why is a rectangle shifted on a canvas？

Tags: javascript, canvas, touch

I have a canvas, I test on mobile, when I touch on the right side of the canvas, the rect is shifted to the right. The more I touch to the left, the more the rect is drawn where it is supposed to be, exactly at the location of the touch. Would you know why？The right part of the canvas is bugging, the left part is ok.

[image]

```
<canvas id="layerDraw"
style="position: relative; width:100%; height:auto; margin- top:2%; z-index: 2; border:1px solid red;">
</canvas>

function touch(){
ld.addEventListener("touchstart", follow);
ld.addEventListener("touchmove", follow);
}
function follow(evt){
//evt.preventDefault(); 
var ctx = ld.getContext("2d");
var touches = evt.touches;  
ctx.fillStyle = chos; 
var x = touches[0].pageX -getOffsetLeft(ld);
var y = touches[0].pageY -getOffsetTop(ld);
    ctx.fillRect(x-5,y, 20, 20);
}
function getOffsetLeft( elem ) { 
var offsetLeft = 0; 
do { 
    if (!isNaN(elem.offsetLeft)) { 
        offsetLeft += elem.offsetLeft; 
    } 
} while( elem = elem.offsetParent ); 
return offsetLeft; 
}

function getOffsetTop( elem ) { 
var offsetTop = 0; 
do { 
    if (!isNaN(elem.offsetTop)) { 
        offsetTop += elem.offsetTop; 
    } 
} while( elem = elem.offsetParent ); 
return offsetTop; 
}
```

Comment: set the canvas width and height in `px` terms not using style and test.

Comment: @Alireza thanks it works, but I wanted the width of the window, so it fills the entire window in portrait or landscape mode.

Comment: I'm not that savvy with canvas, but maybe it'd help to set the canvas width dynamically reading the window's width?

Comment: Great thanks @Alireza it works fine